# How to add image(.jpg) to OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, dem, image

This is my website for test: http://www.cv.nctu.edu.tw/shapefile-js-openlayers/ol_simple.html

My dem data is (.jpg).

```
var inProj = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:3826');
var outProj = map.getProjectionObject();
var options = {   
    opacity: 1.0, 
    isBaseLayer: false,
    numZoomLevels: 20 
};

var extent = new OpenLayers.Bounds(16120,2409591,484824,2814500).transform(inProj,outProj);

var imageLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Image('Image Layer',  
    'http://www.cv.nctu.edu.tw/shapefile-js-openlayers/naturalearthdata/cultural/dem.jpg', 
    extent,
    new OpenLayers.Size(1,1),
    options);
map.addLayers([osm, GridshpLayer,BounderyshpLayer,RivershpLayer,SeashpLayer,imageLayer]);
```

error:
[image]

Comment: Hi, have you tried googling it? Since you are using an old version of OpenLayers: check out http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26430/help-displaying-jpg-in-openlayers

Comment: Notice also that OpenLayers.Layer.Image most probably does not support .img format directly but you must convert it to jpg, png or somethign else. List of supported formats is unclear http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110291/openlayers-supported-image-formats.

Comment: OK thanks. I already tried it. But I used wrong keyword and couldn't find. I will try more keyword. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is *completely* unrelated to your question's title.

The JS interpreter doesn't even reach the line where you add the image layer because of an earlier `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'proj' of null"` exception in the following line:

```js
var extent = new OpenLayers.Bounds(16120,2409591,484824,2814500).transform(inProj,outProj)
```

This is because `outProj` is null - apparently map is not yet initialized fully so `map.getProjectionObject();` returns `null`. You can test this by removing the reprojection:

```js
var extent = new OpenLayers.Bounds(16120,2409591,484824,2814500);
```

Even though the page clearly still doesn't work correctly, you won't get fatal JS exceptions and you'll see the map rendered.